# Import sklearn fails - conflict with numpy version?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to import sklearn module in the interactive python environment, but I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 11, in <module>
from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
  File "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash (sklearn/utils/murmurhash.c:5029)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

I read somewhere that this might be a problem derived by the fact that scikit-learn is compiled against an older version of numpy, but I tried to uninstall and reinstall both numpy and scikit-learn (and scipy to be sure) and the problem persists.

These are my python modules:

```
giacomopoli$ pip freeze
Warning: cannot find svn location for setuptools===0.6c12dev-r88846
altgraph==0.10.1
appnope==0.1.0
attrs==15.2.0
backports-abc==0.4
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1
bdist-mpkg==0.4.4
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
bonjour-py==0.3
certifi==2016.2.28
cssselect==0.9.1
decorator==4.0.9
functools32==3.2.3.post2
gnureadline==6.3.3
ipykernel==4.3.1
ipython==4.1.2
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
ipywidgets==4.1.1
Jinja2==2.8
jsonschema==2.5.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==4.1.1
jupyter-console==4.1.1
jupyter-core==4.0.6
lxml==3.5.0
macholib==1.5
MarkupSafe==0.23
matplotlib==1.1.1
mistune==0.7.2
modulegraph==0.10.1
nbconvert==4.1.0
nbformat==4.0.1
notebook==4.1.0
numpy==1.10.4
path.py==8.1.2
pexpect==4.0.1
pickleshare==0.6
protobuf==3.0.0b2
ptyprocess==0.5.1
py2app==0.7.1
pyasn1==0.1.9
pyasn1-modules==0.0.8
Pygments==2.1.3
PyInstaller==3.1.1
pyobjc-core==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-Automator==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-CoreData==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-CoreText==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-InterfaceBuilderKit==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-Message==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-PubSub==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-QTKit==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-Quartz==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-WebKit==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-XgridFoundation==2.3.2a0
pyOpenSSL==0.13
PyRSS2Gen==1.0.0
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz===2012d
pyzmq==15.2.0
qtconsole==4.2.0
queuelib==1.4.2
scikit-learn==0.17.1
scipy==0.17.0
Scrapy==1.0.5
selenium==2.52.0
service-identity==16.0.0
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.10.0
tensorflow==0.7.1
terminado==0.6
tornado==4.3
traitlets==4.1.0
Twisted==12.2.0
w3lib==1.13.0
xattr==0.6.4
zope.interface==3.8.0
```

I've Python 2.7 and OSX 10.9.5.
What do I have to do in order to get things work?

Comment: I think you need to upgrade your numpy library package.  "pip install --upgrade numpy"

Comment: My version is the 1.10, which is the latest one, except for the 1.11 under development I think.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had multiple versions of python installed (2.3, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7) and multiple version of Numpy. The one used in the interactive shell was numpy 1.6. I erased them all and installed the new one with numpy and now it works.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as you, how did you figure out that you had multiple versions of python and of numpy?

Comment: I figured it out, you can find the version of numpy being imported by doing: print numpy.__version__ and then you can see the fault at print numpy.__file__ and it was pointing to an old version in the mac, the solution is to just delete the folder

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. I compared the result of `pip freeze` with the result of `numpy.version` and then deleted the folder (it turned out I had 4 version installed!)